# When is initializer_list allowed to be deduced?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17

I know there are special rules for when initializer_list can be deduced but until discovering the following I somehow thought that was never. What are the rules for when it is OK to deduce or omit `initializer_list` ?

The following example seems ilogical and feels almost like a language deficit ?

```
#include <initializer_list>

void test() {
    bool reverse = true;
    const auto ascend = {1,2,3};//OK : seems to deduce to std::initializer_list<const int>

    //const auto a_or_d_AUTO = reverse ? {3,2,1} : {1,2,3};//not ok, why ?

    const auto i = reverse ? 3 : 1;// also fine

    const auto a_or_d = reverse ? std::initializer_list<const int>({3,2,1}) : std::initializer_list<const int>({1,2,3});//also OK
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/1sNcu4

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This has nothing to do with deduction. The grammar for `?:` requires actual expressions for all three operands:

[[expr.cond]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.cond):

```
conditional-expression:
    logical-or-expression
    logical-or-expression ? expression : assignment-expression
```

A *braced-init-list* is not an expression and simply can't be used with `?:`.

Comment: While your answer is not incorrect it is very sparse - considering future users coming here. Please for example update your answer with why `const auto ascend = {1,2,3};` is fine even while {1,2,3} is not an expression ? Also it would be worth mentioning that the only reason its not an expression is because the comittee decided against it and what, if any, are the possibilities this may change in future. Thank you.

Comment: @darune You can't expect everyone trying to help you to write an encyclopedia article about the subject. It seems like you know more about this than you let on, or at least you know what to look for. The answer is succinct, to the point, and overall clear. Extending it with standardeze and "today"-like statements about what is going on in the committee will conflate it and reduce its overall usefulness. If you want to know that, ask a different question.

Comment: @darune More to the point, you tagged this question `language-lawyer`. You got a language lawyer answer (literally). T.C. is, ah, somewhat of an expert.

Comment: The cited portion of the Standard is [\[expr.cond/7.6.16\]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.cond). A *braced-init-list* is a declaration, not an expression (see [\[dlc.init/9.3\]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init) and [\[dcl.init.list/9.3.4\]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list)).

Comment: @JonHarper A *braced-init-list* is not a declaration. I guess you could call it an initializer.